# y-axis dynamic domain padding to center graph

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I know that this is just a math problem. But can someone help me figure out how to add extra numbers on a graph's y-axis?

Aside from the values shown, this axis can be thousands and even millions. I'm trying to center the lines so the min (-30) and max (98) don't go over the limit. Same would be true if the values are in thousands or millions.

[image]

Comment: If it's just a math problem, you should have asked it on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: ok. thank you for your big help. i will post it there.

Comment: You should delete this one then.

Comment: i posted it there: http://math.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/149798. but it's not getting much views. :(